# How To Tell My Program That If It Finds The Given String To Run The Code Beneath

Tags: c++

Currently I am error trapping in my program that if my webscraper is sent a link that shows "Quote Not Found Page For WSJ Market Data" in the source of the page that it will set all my variables to 0, but when I run my code even if i type in a website that I know should work it sets all my variables to 0, im assuming thats because my if statement is always being true but i cant figure out the work around to tell it to only be true if it finds that string, my code is below, I know string::npos is something that can be used to determine if it finds the string im looking for with .find().

```
if(html.find("Quote Not Found page for WSJ Market Data") != string::npos)
    {
         peRatio = 0;
         pcfRatio = 0;
         pbRatio = 0;
         psRatio = 0;
         qtrEpsEstimate = 0;
         annEpsEst = 0;
         qtrLastYear = 0;
         annLastYear = 0;
         totalCash = "";
         totalDebt = "";
         totalLiabilites = "";
         bookValueTotal = 0;
         totalDebtEquity = 0;
         totalDebtCapital = 0;
         totalDebtAssets = 0;
         interestCoverage = 0;
         lastReport = "";
         nextReport = "";
         fiscalEnd = "";
    }

    else
    {
```

Comment: What are the values initially initialised as, or are they just declared. Depending on your complier, the values could be 0 from the very beginning.

Comment: @Vedant In the else statement which should occur more often than this if statement, the values are then assigned to what they are suppose to be .